# Maven build gets connection reset when downloading artifacts

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, amazon-ec2, maven-central

We have a maven build that runs in jenkins in amazon ec2 instances.
The total build takes 20-30min and roughly every other run it fails because it cant download artifacts from maven central. This is the failing part of the log:

```
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/2.18.1/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.18.1.pom
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
Feb 03, 2017 3:39:00 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
```

The interesting thing is that it runs fine for 20min downloading from maven central and our own repos, but then fails on the exact same download every other time. This makes me think it's not due to connection problems, as then it would fail on other downloads randomly.

After googling I found that it could be because of Ipv4 vs Ipv6 issues, so I tried setting java.net.prefetIPv4stack=true in the build, but that didn't help.

The command to run mvn is:

```
mvn -X -e clean deploy -U -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

I've also tried to increase -Xmx in both MAVEN_OPTS and JAVA_OPTS (I read somewhere that maven needs to be able to keep all dependencies in RAM, not sure if true tho), but without success.

Do you have any other ideas that I can try?

Edit: Added stacktrace

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.18.1: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.18.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleMappingDelegate.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateLifecycleMappings(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:266)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:jar:2.18.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:pom:2.18.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
    ... 47 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: Please run mvn with the paramter -X to enable debug output. Please post the output.

Comment: Could be a time out?  Do you have the possibility of keeping your downloaded artifacts in your local repository?  This way, there is no need to download them over the Internet anymore.

Comment: I ran again with -X and updated the output/ added the stacktrace @GKR.

Comment: @toongeorges Thats one solution, but I would rather make it work as it should if possible

Comment: The exception says that Maven cannot download the file https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/2.18.1/maven-failsafe-plugin-2.18.1.pom
This file is there, so there must be something wrong with your Internet connection.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have a really similar problem right now.

Comment: @david unfortunately not, tried all the suggestions here without any luck. The project was then put on ice so we decided to leave it as is.

Comment: I have spent some time banging my head against this, and have some findings that might help.
Context is, we run CI on AWS and were getting occasional - too many to ignore - errors where Maven would fail to download dependencies, and mostly "Connection reset" ones.
One helper was like @Barchetta says to upgrade to Maven 3.6.0+ because that includes configurable retries.
We also separately introduced a dependency cache, which I can recommend. No sense having all our CI machines download dependencies again and again.
See next comment for more!

Comment: (continued) But one case remained and caused us problems, namely `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset` - that one isn't retried by default because `SSLException` is in the default list of non-retryable exceptions.
So last leg of our solution was to exclude `SSLException` from that list, preferring robustness over latency.

Comment: Tl;dr: `mvn [...] -Dmaven.wagon.http.retryhandler.nonRetryableClasses=java.io.InterruptedIOException,java.net.UnknownHostException,java.net.ConnectException`

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR**

Try upgrading to Maven 3.6.1. It has a new version of Wagon HTTP with improved retry behavior. This fixed the problem for us.

**Background**

Our builds ran fine for months (in ec2). Then one day they started sporadically failing downloading Maven artifacts (from Maven central) with Connection reset. We never got to the bottom of it. Maybe something in ec2 changed. Maybe something in our build changed. Dunno.

The bottom line is that networks are unreliable, and Maven (or more specifically Wagon) was not very resilient to connection failures. Thankfully it looks like they've improved that.

Maven 3.6.1 includes a new version of Wagon that supports configureable retry behavior. By default it appears to have a retry count of 3 -- which was good enough for us. Some details:

- [Wagon Configuration properties](https://maven.apache.org/wagon/wagon-providers/wagon-http/): describes how to configure retry behavior.
- [WAGON-526](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WAGON-526): the issue requesting configurable retry handling
- [The PR for WAGON-526](https://github.com/apache/maven-wagon/pull/37/files): from this you can inspect the source and see the default values for the configuration properites

Comment: We still have this issue with 3.6.3

Answer (score 3):

Few Pointers,

1) This looks to be EC2 network setting problem. It's not a maven http wagon problem.

2) Look at this similar [problem](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222925). More specifically [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout).

3) You can temporarily try following.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=10
```

Hope it helps you in solving your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your tips! Unfortunately, they didn't solve the problem. I tried some different setups with lower keepalive_time and more probes as well, but the problem remains

Comment: Could you try switching to http instead of https ? Check your distribution management in settings.xml OR your pom.xml. Change repository access to http instead https instead. If it works, then it surely is a problem of firewall configuration.

Comment: AWS forums link is broken as of 2023/07/28 :(

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar issue in Azure VM. I posted this question here as well: [Maven build download artefacts connection slow/reset when running inside a Docker Container on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269584/maven-build-download-artefacts-connection-slow-reset-when-running-inside-a-docke)

Our setup is a bit more complex - we run a docker container that includes a build step for maven.

Both when running the Container in ACI and in an Azure VM - we encounter the same issue, the maven central downloads timeout or succeeded but at very slow speeds.

```
14:10:48,505 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-0] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar
14:10:48,506 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-2] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons/1.7/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons-1.7.jar
14:10:48,505 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-1] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-git-commons/1.7/maven-scm-provider-git-commons-1.7.jar
14:10:48,521 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-3] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/tmatesoft/sqljet/sqljet/1.0.4/sqljet-1.0.4.jar
14:10:48,523 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-4] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.1.3/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar
14:10:48,540 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-0] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/regexp/regexp/1.3/regexp-1.3.jar (25 kB at 706 kB/s)
14:10:48,540 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-0] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2/stringtemplate-3.2.jar
14:10:48,564 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-0] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2/stringtemplate-3.2.jar (172 kB at 4.0 MB/s)
14:26:32,150 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-2] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/scm/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons/1.7/maven-scm-provider-cvs-commons-1.7.jar (80 kB at 84 B/s)
14:26:32,157 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-4] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.1.3/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar (151 kB at 159 B/s)
14:26:32,199 [BasicRepositoryConnector-repo.maven.apache.org-27-3] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/tmatesoft/sqljet/sqljet/1.0.4/sqljet-1.0.4.jar (744 kB at 788 B/s)
```

Notice the suspicious: (151 kB at 159 B/s), (80 kB at 84 B/s), (744 kB at 788 B/s)
We have examples of executions that run just fine - and examples of executions that timeout (1 hour) - and examples of executions that take close to 1h.

We have attempted to alter the mvn command - we initially ran:

`mvn clean package`

but then we added:

`mvn compile dependency:resolve`

`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`

`mvn clean package`

These changes only altered the place where the connection slows down - instead of downloading some jars, it slowed down at dowloading .pom files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. We had a similar issue with a "Connection reset" when downloading Maven dependencies running the build inside CodeBuild. Splitting the "mvn clean verify" into 

"mvn clean compile && mvn dependency:resolve-plugins && mvn verify"

I don't know why but making the dependencies and plugins be downloaded before running the tests solved the issue.