# Maven artifact transfer fails in AWS due to Connection reset errors

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Facing some issues when building with Maven in AWS ECS. Not entirely sure what the problem is at the moment.

FYI this build runs on a docker container on an EC2 host

> telnet is fine.

```
[root@host ~]# telnet repo.maven.apache.org 443
Trying 151.101.60.215...
Connected to repo.maven.apache.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

> For the most part it downloads up to a point.

```
07:52:10 [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ hybris-package ---
07:52:10 [DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
07:52:10 [DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
07:52:10 Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.pom
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Connection reset
07:52:13 May 09, 2018 7:52:13 AM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
07:52:13 INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
07:52:13
```

Bit perplexed, traffic would be routed via the NAT gateways. There are some interesting articles on the use of NAT's but none of which purport to reasoning enough to effect this simple use case.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128815, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout, https://stackoverflow.com/a/42025497/592355 (these links handle (explain) same/similar issue ... and the answer looks like a "fix"!)